# HTML5 Background Color fill too big

Tags: html, css

When I try to make an HTML background color fill for a div, it ends up with a huge amount of extra space at the bottom - I want to make a sort of header, but it becomes really wide. Can someone help me with this?

My HTML is

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>Welcome to My Site</h1>
</div>
```

My CSS is

```
div.header{
  background-color:grey;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: please add more code - some html would help

Comment: Please create an example (in a code snippet, for example) that shows exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend adding width, height, and margin to your code. You can experiment with your code with a website like codepen.io! Below is a link to an example of what I'm talking about.

https://codepen.io/wykydtronik/pen/VpEGer

```
div.header{
  background-color:grey;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you look at the CSS code you will see I set a width of 350px, and height of 150px. I also added a margin: 0 auto; to make the header div to be center. It's a neat trick that isn't intuitive until you've seen it a few times.

Let me know if this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use bootstrap, there is lots of community support and documentation and you can even override colors and styles for yourself.

Bootstrap well class could work for you.

```
<div class="well">
  Look, I'm in a well!
</div>
```

Or the jumbotron for bigger impact.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Jumbotron</h1>
  <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
```